# change things from a required lua file, corona sdk

Tags: lua, coronasdk, require

When I require a file1, I can export the values, data or objects to file2, but file2 can't export to file1

(With "file" I mean a lua file, example, Scene1.lua, Data.lua)

How can I export from file2 to file1 and viceversa?

example code

Data.lua (file1)

```
--data.lua

local M = {}

local money = 500
local moneyText = display.newText("Money: " .. money, 
display.contentCenterX, display.contentCenterY, "calibri", 50)

M.moneyText = moneyText
M.moneyData = money

return M
```

file2

```
 --file2.lua

local Data = require("data")

local moneyText2 = Data.moneyText
local moneyData = Data.moneyData

local function addSomeValue()
moneyData = moneyData + 1
end

timer.performWithDelay(1000, addSomeValue, 0)
```

Comment: you don't export data from file1 you load and run code written in file1. what exactly do you want to achieve? I'm sure you have some misunderstanding of how this works.

Comment: Ooh, I thinked that with require the file1 was exported, not loaded, I want to change the money value in file1 from file2, how does I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
local Data = require("data")
```

is more or less equivalent to

```
function chunkFromDataLua()

  local M = {}

  local money = 500
  local moneyText = display.newText("Money: " .. money, 
  display.contentCenterX, display.contentCenterY, "calibri", 50)

  M.moneyText = moneyText
  M.moneyData = money

  return M

end

local Data = chunkFromDataLua()
```

`Data` now refers to table `M`

```
local money = 500
M.moneyData = money
```

only creates a copy of money and stores that in M. So changing M.moneyData will not affect money. Hence changing Data.moneyData will also not affect money.

In addition to that

```
local moneyText = display.newText("Money: " .. money, 
  display.contentCenterX, display.contentCenterY, "calibri", 50)
```

creates a display object with a static text using the value of `money` at that moment. So changing the value of `money` after that won't change the content of your text display. You have to change `Data.moneyText.text` to do that.